# How can I connect to another WP database and use WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I can connect to the other database with `$db2 = new wpdb( $user, $pass, $db, $host );`, but **how to I get `WP_Query()` to use `$db2`**?

I want to be able to use the loop just the same with `$db2` as I can with the original connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WP_Query` uses the global `$wpdb`. What you'll have to do is replace `$wpdb`, use `WP_Query`, then set it back when you're done.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb_backup = $wpdb;
$wpdb = new wpdb( $user, $pass, $db, $host );
# Do your stuff here...
# then when done...
$wpdb = $wpdb_backup;
```

Comment: @s_ha_dum Hah, it's gone the other way a few times lately! I think your fingers are usually a little quicker than mine.

Comment: and how could we close that new connection ..?

Comment: This didn't work for me out of the box. Had to set the prefix as well `$wpdb->prefix('wp_');`.

Comment: A late but valid comment... it is important to call `wp_flush_cache()` after setting `$wpdb` to the new connection and again when assigning it back to `$wpdb_backup`.  *Sometimes* you are still connected to the previous database and calling `wp_flush_cache()` ensures that you are not.

Comment: @joehanna wp_cache_flush() not wp_flush_cache()

Comment: Oops! Thanks  @shaunsantacruz. Nice catch